# Which is the Shiva beej mantra?

Tags: shiva, mantras

Which is the beej mantra of Shiva Haum or Hraum and what is the difference between the two?
Can someone who is not initiated still chant these beejas?

Answer (score 1):

Beej mantra for Shiva is 'haum'. The **Varadātantra text** explains it as follows:

**[Verse](https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/learning-sanskrit-sacred-mantra-s-haum/475):**

[image]

**Meaning / translation:** The letter (kāraḥ) "**ha**" (ha) (is) certainly (tu) expressive (vācī) of Śiva (śiva), (and) the letter (kāraḥ) "**au**" (au) is (syāt) Sadāśiva (sadāśivaḥ). Śūnya or Void (śūnyam) means (artham) destroyer (hara) of pain (duḥkha) indeed (tu). **Therefore (tasmāt), one should worship (yajet) (Lord) Śiva (śivam) by means of that (seed-mantra) (tena)||**